# numpy.std versus pythons statistics.stdev , floating point precision

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain to me why the python package does yield the exact value for the standard deviation and numpy not? Python uses the function `_ss` in its [source_code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/statistics.py) to calculate the sum of squared residuals. It seems that the substraction does yield exactly zero. The numpy documentation states that [results can be inaccurate depending on the precision of the input data](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)

Why is python more accurate here than numpy?

```
import statistics
import numpy as np
a = 3.28*np.ones(100)
print(f'STD with numpy {np.std(a)}')
print(f'STD with pythons statistics package {statistics.stdev(a)}')

STD with numpy 4.440892098500626e-16
STD with pythons statistics package 0.0
```

Comment: It is indeed a numerical artefact caused by the underlying method of numpy. If you give numbers that can be represented *exactly* in IEEE 754 floating point, you get a 0: `a = 3.25 * np.ones(100)` (0.25 is 1/(2*2) so *exact*), `np.std(a)` gives 0.0

Comment: @SergeBallesta do you know why python differs here? I am courious to know whether this is due to a different formula or due to the software itself. E.g https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/28/theoretical-explanation-for-numerical-results/

Comment: If I knew, I would have posted an answer... More seriously I'm afraid that the answer can only be found in numpy source code for `np.var`.

Comment: also note they use different conventions for sample/population.  `stddev(x)` is equivalent to `np.std(x, ddof=1)`, while `statistics.pstddev` is what `np.std` does by default.  `0*sqrt(99/100)` is still `0` but in general it's better to use the appropriate one

Comment: @SamMason Thank you, yes I am aware of it. But the degrees of freedom in the denominator do not influence the precision of the results.